# using loc in a conditional search for length of a split string within a series of strings in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df`:

```py
         A
0   Foo
1   Foo Bar
2   Foo,Bar,Quux
3   FooBar Qux,Quux
```

and i'd like to locate rows using `loc` like so:

```py
df.loc[(len(df['A'].str.split(',')) > 1)]
```

to retrieve rows:

```py
2   Foo,Bar,Quux
3   FooBar Qux,Quux
```

however this syntax doesn't work. What is the correct syntax for `loc` in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) for get length:

```
df.loc[(df['A'].str.split(',').str.len() > 1)]
```

Or use [`Series.str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html):

```
df.loc[(df['A'].str.count(',') > 0)]
```

Comment: Perfect. the first makes much clearer sense to me now seeing it as just calling a method on a returned Series - I'd thought the return type was a list - hence the error. Cheers.

The second solution is a kind of workaround I was trying to avoid so as to understand what was wrong with my syntax